# When we are deleting foreign key constraint data its show error . how we can get error in proper way so that show to user

Tags: yii2

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`m_travel`.`location__city`, CONSTRAINT `location__city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `location__country` (`id`))
The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM location__country WHERE id=2
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1451
    [2] => Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`m_travel`.`location__city`, CONSTRAINT `location__city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `location__country` (`id`))
)

Comment: database query
$connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $model = $connection->createCommand('DELETE FROM location__country WHERE id=:userid');

        $model->bindParam(':userid', $userid);

        $userid = 2;

        if ($model->execute() === false) {
            throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to delete the object for unknown reason.');
        }

Comment: how to get boolean value that itis deletedv or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
try {
    // delete command here
} catch (\yii\db\Exception $e) {
    if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1451) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'Failed to delete the object.');
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```